# react onclick data-value return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change my state alignment to: left, center, right or justify, depending on which `<Icon />` I've clicked. But, `e.target.getAttribute('data-value')` is returning `null`.

When I change `<Icon icon="align-left" />` by `left`, it's working. `e.target.getAttribute('data-value')` is returning data-value.

So, how can I change my state to left, right center or justify on click of my `<Icon />`?

```
class TextStyleParams extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickAlignment = this.onClickAlignment.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      textStyle: {
        alignment: 'left',
        ...,
      },
    };
  }

  onClickAlignment(e) {
    const { textStyle } = this.state;
    const newTextStyle = {
      ...textStyle,
      alignment: e.target.getAttribute('data-value'),
    };
    this.setState({ textStyle: newTextStyle });
    this.props.updateTextStyle(newTextStyle);
  }
    
  render() {
    const { textStyle } = this.state;
        
    return (
      <div>
        <span role="button" onClick={this.onClickAlignment} data-value="left"><Icon icon="align-left" /></span>
        <span role="button" onClick={this.onClickAlignment} data-value="center"><Icon icon="align-center" /></span>
        <span role="button" onClick={this.onClickAlignment} data-value="right"><Icon icon="align-right" /></span>
        <span role="button" onClick={this.onClickAlignement} data-value="justify"><Icon icon="align-justify" /></span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Icon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { icon } = this.props;
    return (
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" styleName="icon" className={`icon-${icon}`}>
        <use xlinkHref={`iconset.svg#${icon}`} />
      </svg>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value')`. The `target` property refers to the dom element on which the event originated (which will be the `svg` element), whereas `currentTarget` refers to the element to which the handler was attached.

Comment: Thanks a ton. With `e.target` the result was weird - null sometimes. Plus, it took forever to return the correct value.

Comment: You're welcome! Nice to see an answer from 2017 helping out someone after all that time.